# Saving Form data to file

Tags: javascript, html, file, save

I want make a simple HTML application with a form. I want to be able to save the data to a file and also read it.

It will be an application that is just for offline use (me and 1 other person will use it). But since I won't be the only one using it I want to be able to share the data with the other person.

So using local storage is not an option. That data cannot be saved, and I don't accidently want to lose that data.
I also tried using blobs, but that only offers download option and it downloads to your download folder. I would like to save the file to the location of the HTML file.

Is that possible with plain HTML and JS? Or do I need to look into some other technologies?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Will you and that 1 other person be using it from the same browser on the same workstation?  Or are you on different computers?

Answer (score 0):

Browser javascript don't have access to the file system and so it won't allow to create file in the local directory. if you want to achieve such functionality you should try sending the file to backend like node js and write the file to the directory.